# easiest way to create permission set in sfdx project

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, permission-sets

Let's say i need to create new Permset. What is the best way to create .xml inside sfdx project  `premissionsets` folder? What are the rules of naming? Where can I get details about .xml contents?

Answer (score 5):

It is generally much easier to build your Permission Set in a Salesforce org, preferably a scratch org, and capture it as source than it is to directly author the XML metadata.

The latter is *possible*, but it's clunky unless you happen to have or build tooling to generate the markup for you.

In Salesforce DX source format, Permission Sets are stored in files ending in `.permissionset-meta.xml`. The [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm) documentation covers the details of the XML structure.

Comment: sfdx force:source:pull does it easily in a scratch org, and you don't even need to track the changes yourself.

Comment: force:source:pull is great, I love when I can actually use a scratch org, but it doesn't help with creating one in the first place. I find the setup pages so painful to work with, I came here hoping for dx native build option. Now I'm sad.